# Detectar repetição de dígitos em Java

Tags: java, algoritmo

Preciso fazer um programa que leia um número inteiro positivo N. Após ler esse numero, o programa deve avaliar se existem digitos repetidos no numero.

Por exemplo: em 234571 não há dígitos repetidos. 
outro exemplo: em 7656 há dígitos repetidos.

Tem que ser feito em java e se possível sem usar vetor, minha duvida é como fazer essa verificação por que ele não pode digitar um numero com dígitos iguais, entendeu?

```
package lista01;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex08 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = 0, a, b, c, d, contarDigitos = 0;

    System.out.println("Digite um numero de quatro digitos diferentes");
    num = ler.nextInt();

    contarDigitos = (int) (Math.log10(num) + 1);

    if (contarDigitos == 4) {
        d = num / 1000;
        a = (num / 100) % 10;
        b = (num % 100) / 10;
        c = (num % 10) % 10;

        System.out.println("Resultado:" + d + a + b + c);
    } else {
        System.out.println("O numero precisa ter 4 digitos execute novamente!");
    }


   }
}
```

não sei como vou verificar se esses números são diferentes

Comment: Tem como fazer sem usar vetor?

Comment: Então a mensagem diz que precisam ser 4 dígitos, e todos diferentes? Se sim, você colocaria essas 2 validações, correto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, pensei em uma solução que talvez não seja muito eficiente mas pelo menos não usa vetor. Como tem apenas 10 dígitos possíveis, você poderia ter 10 variáveis (o que soa estranho e seria melhor usar um vetor de 10 posições, mas enfim) em que cada uma é uma flag pra saber se determinado dígito já apareceu. Por exemplo, `int flag1`, `int flag2` e assim por diante. Aí em um laço vc percorre os dígitos e verifica se é igual às flags. Se isso acontecer duas vezes você sabe que o dígito apareceu duas vezes.